# How to change Date Time Picker enabled hours using on change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have the following picker:

```js
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT',
    locale: 'PT-BR',
    icons: {
      up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
      down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
      time: "far fa-clock",
    },
    enabledHours: permittedHours(),
    stepping: 15,
  });
```

But I want to call other aux function on re-set the enabledHours case the input value changes.

I chained this and could successfully pop the alert:

```js
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT',
    locale: 'PT-BR',
    icons: {
      up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
      down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
      time: "far fa-clock",
    },
    enabledHours: permittedHours(),
    stepping: 15,
  })
  .on('dp.change', function (e) { 
    alert(e.date._i)
  });
```

But I if I try to deal with enabledHours it doesn't work. How can I pass a new value to enabledHours in this case?

Answer (score -1):

```js
on('dp.change', function (e) {
     $('.datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").enabledHours(your_function(e.date.format('yourformat')));
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate in plain language ( that of the OP preferably ) what your code does, and how it resolves the OP's question related to the content in the body.